# WooCommerce hide specific product if stock drops bellow a specific number

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm having a hard time to automatically hide some products based on id from shop loop, search etc if the stock drops bellow a specific number.
I'm trying to do this because I'm trying to reserve lets say 20 items from that product so they can be sold elsewhere.

functions.php

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_hide_out_of_stock_items', 'set_out_of_stock_product_qty_less_than' );
function set_out_of_stock_product_qty_less_than( $hide ) {
    global $product;
    
    $product_id = 2004891;
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    
    //$prodid = $product->get_id();
    //$stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    if ( $stock <= 174) {
        $hide = 'yes';
    }
    return $hide;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_specific_products_from_shop', 20, 2);

function hide_specific_products_from_shop($q, $query) {
    if (is_admin())
        return;

    $product_id = 2004891;
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    if ($stock <= 176) {
        $q->set('post__not_in', array($product_id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide from shop page through this hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'woo_custom_product__query' );
function woo_custom_product_query( $q ) {
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => '_stock',
        'value'     => '5', // your prefered stock value
        'compare'   => '>'
    );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```